# Partial measurement (destructive) collapses |1> to |0>

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

In the [following QScript program](http://qcplayground.withgoogle.com/#/playground/5662197925543936):

```
VectorSize 6

// The system can be in only one state - |000001>
SigmaX 0

// Non-destructive full measurement returns 1, as expected
Measure
Print measured_value

// Destructive measurement collapses the last qubit to |0>?
MeasureBit 0

Measure
Print measured_value
```

Why does the last qubit collapse to |0> when it's in fact |1>? Is this a bug in the simulator or did I misunderstand how the partial destructive measurement should work? In the [about page](http://qcplayground.withgoogle.com/#/about) they give an example where a qubit collapses to |1>, so it should be possible...

Cross-posted on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539926/partial-measurement-destructive-collapses-1-to-0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. A destructive partial measurement will result in a deterministic bit. But it will never collapse to the state with zero probability as in your example. I have tried the example in their about page of the `MeasureBit(b)`. However, after the partial measurement, the state always corresponds to the measurement result of 0, no matter whether the actual measurement result give 0 of 1. So it is a bug.

```
// Trying MeasureBit() desribed in the about page http://qcplayground.withgoogle.com/#/about
VectorSize 6

// Create 4 qubit state with equal probability
Hadamard 0
Hadamard 1
Hadamard 2
Hadamard 3

// Measure the most significant bit
MeasureBit 3
Print measured_value
```

Comment: I'll just accept your answer, thanks for confirming that I'm not *that* mistaken about this :) Guess I'll have to look for a better simulator, which is kind of sad because I liked the state visualisations of this one...

Comment: @VladislavZorov I have emailed them and I will let you know the result.

Comment: I did the same even before I was sure this is a bug, but no reply so far.